# Issues getting my in app purchases to work in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am trying to put two in-app purchases in my code. 
It works with the first one (removeAds) but when I try to add the second one I get errors and nothing works.

I attached the full code below. What do I need to fix to get the second in app purchase (unlockPhrases)to work with no errors and where did I go wrong?

```
@IBOutlet var unlockPhrasesLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var unlockPhrasesResult: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var removeAdsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var removeAdsResult: UILabel!

var activeProduct: SKProduct?

@IBAction func removeAds(_ sender: Any) {
    if let activeProduct = activeProduct {
        print("Buying \(activeProduct.productIdentifier)")

        let payment = SKPayment(product: activeProduct)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    } else {
          print("No product")
    }
}

//Added
@IBAction func unlockPhrases(_ sender: Any) {
    if let activeProduct = activeProduct {
        print("Buying \(activeProduct.productIdentifier)")

        let payment = SKPayment(product: activeProduct)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    } else {
        print("No product")
    }
}

//Added ended
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("Loaded products")

    for product in response.products {
        print("Product: \(product.productIdentifier), \(product.localizedTitle), \(product.price.floatValue)")

        removeAdsLabel.text = "Buy \(product.localizedTitle)"
        activeProduct = product
    }
}

//Added
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("Loaded products")

    for product in response.products {
        print("Product: \(product.productIdentifier), \(product.localizedTitle), \(product.price.floatValue)")

        unlockPhrasesLabel.text = "Buy \(product.localizedTitle)"
        activeProduct = product
    }
}

//added ended
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case .purchased:
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            print("Purchased")
            removeAdsResult.text = "Purchased"
        case .failed:
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            print("Failed")
            removeAdsResult.text = "Failed"
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

//Added
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case .purchased:
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            print("Purchased")
            unlockPhrasesResult.text = "Purchased"
        case .failed:
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            print("Failed")
            unlockPhrasesResult.text = "Failed"
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

//added ended
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)

    let productIdentifiers: Set<String> = ["removeAds", "mensPhrases"]

    let productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
    productsRequest.delegate = self
    productsRequest.start()
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 copies of `productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:` and  2 copies of `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`? You can't compile if you do that, and it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one `productRequest:didReceive:` method and one paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` method.

You need to look at the passed in parameters to decide which product it is associated with. Then you can properly update your app state.

```
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("Loaded products")

    for product in response.products {
        print("Product: \(product.productIdentifier), \(product.localizedTitle), \(product.price.floatValue)")

        if product.productIdentifier == "whatever your remove ads id is" {
            removeAdsLabel.text = "Buy \(product.localizedTitle)"
            activeProduct = product
        } else if product.productIdentifier == "whatever your remove ads id is" {
            unlockPhrasesLabel.text = "Buy \(product.localizedTitle)"
            activeProduct = product
        }
    }
}
```

Make a similar change for the other method.